# PHP mysql Insert/Upload images to database/server naming issues

Tags: php, mysql, insert, naming

I'm building a form to allow users to upload images into a database, as part of an app for an eye doctor. My issue concerns the table containing information on these images (the `shot` table), the columns of this table are:

`ID | Visit_ID | Patient_ID | Img_Filename | Shrunk_img_filename | Subdir | SubSubDir|`

So the table is only storing info about the images. The image files are named with specific conventions. For example, `0000288964r.jpg` is what a file name in the `Img_filename` column would look like. The file names in the next column, `Shrunk_img_filename` are the same except the `r` is replaced with an `s` and the format is `.bmp`. For example, `0000288964s.bmp`. These numbers in the file names are derived from the `ID` column of this table, with a variable number of zeros added to the begining depending on how many digits the `ID` is.

Also, in my form, I've got a file upload input where the user selects the image to be uploaded. This is where my issue comes into the mix..

I want to use the same file names, like shown above, that are stored in my database as the file names for these images when they're uploaded to my server, but I don't to manually go through the database find the next available ID for an image and rename the images at the time of selecting them for upload.

I really don't know if this is possible, but I'd love to hear any ideas about how to make this work or any kind of workaround for this. Thanks. I'll include my code below (my insert statement is ridiculously long due to the 2 CASE Statements used to create my files names so I just included the jist of it)

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $filetmp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileerror = $_FILES['myfile']['error'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

if ( $fileerror > 0){
die("Error Uploading File Code $fileerror.");
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($filetmp,"C:/wamp/www/vixer/images/".$filename);
echo "Upload Complete!";
}

$sqlvisit="INSERT INTO shot (VISIT_ID, PATIENT_ID, IMG_FILENAME, SHRUNK_IMG_FILENAME, SUBDIR, SUBSUBDIR, IMG_FILE_FORMAT, EYE) SELECT (SELECT max(ID) from visit where visit.patient_id =" . $id ."), " . $id . ", (SELECT CASE blah blah), (SELECT CASE blah blah), '9', '1', '124', '0' FROM SHOT WHERE shot.patient_id = " . $id . "";
mysql_query($sqlvisit);
}
?>

<form id="form3" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none;width:300px;background-color: #FFFFFF;"> 
Upload Image(s)..<input type="file" name="myfile"><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I dont think there is a **reliable** way to do this without first creating the record so you get an ID and then moving the file and updating the record with the filenames.

Comment: :-( I think you're right.. but this pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I basically did what prodigitalson suggested...

I `include()` a call to a php file that inserts a new shot(same query as in my question)

Then I `include()` another call to another php file that selects this new row I just inserted and assigns each column of the result row into variables and then into session variables

Then the session variables are used in my script that uploads the image to my server with the `image filename` and also creates a thumbnail image based on my `shrunk image filename`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to just have 2 separate directories Images/R and Images/S. Set the shrunk image to save in the relevant location. You can then set the file path according to whether you want regular size or smaller.